# Filtrar uma consulta usando um atributo no Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho, resumidamente, a seguinte estrutura:

**Fornecedores**: `id | cnpj | razao_social | endereco_id`
**Pessoas**: `id | nome | tipo_pessoa | fornecedor_id`
**Endereco**: `id | logradouro | cep`

**Model - Fornecedor:**

```
public function endereco() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Endereco', 'id', 'endereco_id');
}

public function pessoa() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pessoa');
}
```

**Model - Pessoa:**

```
public function fornecedor() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Fornecedor', 'id', 'fornecedor_id');
}
```

**Model - Endereco:**

```
public function fornecedor() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Fornecedor');
}
```

**FornecedorController:**

```
public function show($id) {
    $fornecedor = Fornecedor::find($id)->with('endereco', 'pessoa')->get();
    return view('admin.fornecedores.visualizar', compact('fornecedor'));
}
```

Quero mostrar um fornecedor, seu endereço e as pessoas relacionadas a ele. A consulta no meu `controller` funciona, porém, quero que a consulta traga apenas as pessoas que tiverem `tipo_pessoa` = `CF` ou `RF`

Como posso usar algo como o '`WHERE`' para fazer isso na consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala brother, vamos la.

É possível fazer Eager Loading

Informações: http://culttt.com/2013/12/30/eager-loading-laravel-4/

Que no seu caso seria algo mais ou menos dê:

```
$Fornecedores = Fornecedores::with(array('fornecedores.pessoa' => function($query)
{
  $query->WhereIn('tipo_pessoa',['CF', 'RF']);
}))->get();
```

Neste exemplo estou passando a condição where para o relacionamento, ou seja, só me retornara os fornecedores onde a pessoa é tipo CF ou RF.

É possível fazer também direto no model:

```
public function pessoa() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Pessoa')->WhereIn('tipo_pessoa',['CF','RF']);
}
```

Precisando só chamar, abraços!

Comment: Usei no model e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado novamente, @juniorb2ss!

Comment: @buback só que no model ele irá impor essa regra para TODO relacionamento. Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como a correta.

Comment: Certo, vou testar das duas formas e ver qual impacta da forma que quero. Muito obrigado.

Comment: uma outra dúvida: como faço pra trazer cidade e estado que também estão em suas respectivas tabelas?

Comment: Como assim? Você quer trazer a cidade que o fornecedor pertence junto com o estado que a cidade pertence?

Comment: Isso, no meu model fornecedor eu só referencio o Endereco, como posso fazer para o endereço buscar a cidade e o estado. Na tabela endereço tem cidade_id e na tabela cidade tem estado_id.

Comment: Só criar relacionamento. `endereco belonsTo cidade` e `cidade belongsTo estado`. Depois é só recuperar com $endereco->cidade->nome; ou $endereco->cidade->estado->nome;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29166/discussion-between-buback-and-juniorb2ss).